# After importing configurable product in magento 'has_options' is zero

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have successfully imported a configurable product (and it's related products). When I open the configurable product in backend I see the related products in the last tab. But they are not displayed in frontend.

This is because the fields `has_options` and `required_options` are zero. The product with entity_id 2 has been created manually in backend and works perfect.

[image: catalog_product_entity table of magento]

When I open the imported product in backend, change nothing and save it - the both values are changing to 1. What is missing in the import to set these fields directly to 1?

I tried this:

```
 $configurableProduct->setHasOptions(TRUE);
```

But this has no effect.

Comment: I am also having this issue (via StoreManager), did you happen to find an alternative to Magmi?

Comment: No. At this time magmi worked fine, for me. After this project I've decided to never work with Magento again, and I didn't ^^ So sorry, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) now... it seems not to be so easy to import products on my own.

Answer (score 3):

After several hours trialing different solutions I resorted to following the save process of a configurable within the admin area, this pointed me towards the below method;

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::save
```

I then discovered, when saving the configurable programmatically getConfigurableAttributesData and getConfigurableProductsData were empty.
This resulted in me creating a custom shell script where I loaded a collection of configurable products, looped and re-saved the data;

```
foreach($_collectionConfigurables as $_configurableProduct){

    // flag to be saved
    $_configurableProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(1);

    // get the configurable attributes
    $_configurableAttributes = $_configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
    $_configurableProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($_configurableAttributes);

    // Build a collection of configurable children
    $_collectionChildren = $_configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();

    // loop the children and save configurable attributes into an array
    $arr = array();
    foreach($_collectionChildren as $_childProduct){
        foreach($_configurableAttributes as $_attr){
            $arr[$_childProduct->getId()][] = array(
                'attribute_id' => $_attr['attribute_id'],
                'label' => $_childProduct->getAttributeText($_attr['attribute_code']),
                'value_index' => $_childProduct->getData($_attr['attribute_code'])
            );
        }
    }

    $_configurableProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($arr);
    $_configurableProduct->save();
    echo "{$_configurableProduct->getId()}\n";

}
```

Please note this has been tried and tested on CE 1.9.2.1